# Share wireless connection for a Windows 7 host and VirtualBox guest

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, internet-connection, connection-sharing

I am using a Windows 7 x64 laptop as my VirtualBox host. And I'd like my single-NIC Linux guest to share the wireless connection of host.

I want my guest to be a network peer of the host, so using NAT is not an option.

I tried to create a bridge connection with wireless NIC and VirtualBox host-only NIC on host. It works at start, but it fails when the laptop restores from sleep. The bridge connection loses its IP, and there is no way to regain it with DHCP, except for removing the bridge and recreating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting bridge networking in the virtual box setting for the guest should do the trick.

But since you are having troubles with DHCP after restoring from the sleep, have you tried using static IP for the linux guest?

Comment: sorry, I was not clear enough..
in my situation, linux guest is using static IP, and wireless NIC of host is gaining IP from router's DHCP.

I'll try bridge networking in virtualbox. thanks.

Comment: can't be more grateful. using bridge in virtualbox's VM settings succeed avoiding the sleep problem, for I no longer need win7's bridge now..after all, it got to working.